# handler.postDelayed() not stopping

Tags: android, handler, postdelayed

I am updating my UI using the handler.postDelayed() but it is not stopping when I'm wanting it to stop. it keeps updating the UI.

```
  int progress = 10;
Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.d( "","entered run ");
            mWaveLoadingView.setCenterTitle(String.valueOf(progress)+"%");
            mWaveLoadingView.setProgressValue(progress);
            progress+=1;
            if(progress==90)
                stopRepeatingTask();

        } finally {
            // 100% guarantee that this always happens, even if
            // your update method throws an exception
            mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
        }
    }
};

void startRepeatingTask() {
    Log.d( "","entered update ");
    mStatusChecker.run();
}

void stopRepeatingTask() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);

}
```

The handler is being started from another method:

```
 Client.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d( "","entered client ");
                    mHandler = new Handler();
                    startRepeatingTask();
                }
            });
```

any idea on how to make it stop?

Comment: Check to see if stopRepeatingTask is getting called.

Comment: @erversteeg checked it just now. yes, it is being called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you call `stopRepeatingTask()` on reaching a certain limit (`progress == 90`). But in the `finally` block, you unconditionally start the next task. You should only start the new task if the limit has not yet been reached:

```
Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.d( "","entered run ");
            mWaveLoadingView.setCenterTitle(String.valueOf(progress)+"%");
            mWaveLoadingView.setProgressValue(progress);
            progress+=1;
            if(progress==90)
                stopRepeatingTask();

        } finally {
            // 100% guarantee that this always happens, even if
            // your update method throws an exception

            // only if limit has not been reached:
            if(progress<90){
                mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
            }
        }
    }
};
```